# Como puedo cambiar valores usando JQuery?

Tags: jquery, script

Necesito cambiar unos valores en un cuadro de opciones pre-establecidos usando `JQuery`, un ejemplo del `code`:

```
<div id="div-archive-max-size">
Max size for archive :
<select name="archive-max-size">
<option value="10485760">10240 Mo</option>
<option value="5242880">5120 Mo</option>
<option value="4194304">4096 Mo</option>
<option value="3145728">3072 Mo</option>
<option value="2097152">2048 Mo</option>
<option value="1048576">1024 Mo</option>
<option value="524288">512 Mo</option>
<option value="262144">256 Mo</option>
<option value="204800">200 Mo</option>
<option value="102400">100 Mo</option>
</select>
</div>
```

La idea es cambiar el valor numérico (`value="10485760"`) mas la descripción (`10240 Mo`) a (`value="17485760"`) y (`17 Gb`) respectivamente, y así con los demás... con valores y descripciones personalizados. Sería un `script` para usar en ´Tampermonkey´ o similar.. 
Alguien me supo dar una respuesta pero sinceramente no se como puedo aplicar la solución, la rta que supieron darme:

> Solo tendrias que recorrer cada `option` del `select` con el metodo `.each()`. Para asignarle el valor al `option` se utilizar la funcion `.val()` y para asignar el texto `.text()`.
>
> Por ejemplo:

```
    function modificar()
{
  var data = [{val: "15485760", text: "15 GB"},{val: "otros valores", text: "otros valores"},{val: "otros valores", text: "otros valores 2"}];
  $("select[name='archive-max-size'] option").each(function(index, element){

    $(element).val(data[index].val)
    .text(data[index].text);

  });
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que explicas, la respuesta sería correcta, aunque yo le agregaría una verificación de tipo (por si el array está incompleto).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valores = [[17485760,'17 Gb'],[223123,'223 Kb']];
  $('select[name=archive-max-size] option').each(function(i,item){
    if(typeof(valores[i]) != 'undefined'){
      $(item).val(valores[i][0]).text(valores[i][1]);
    }
  }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-archive-max-size">
Max size for archive :
<select name="archive-max-size">
<option value="10485760">10240 Mo</option>
<option value="5242880">5120 Mo</option>
<option value="4194304">4096 Mo</option>
<option value="3145728">3072 Mo</option>
<option value="2097152">2048 Mo</option>
<option value="1048576">1024 Mo</option>
<option value="524288">512 Mo</option>
<option value="262144">256 Mo</option>
<option value="204800">200 Mo</option>
<option value="102400">100 Mo</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Genial amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funcionó perfecto!